# Deploy multiple Cloudrun service with same dockerimage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry

There are 25+ Cloudrun services that use the same docker image(from GCR) but are configured with different variables. What is an easy and reliable method to deploy all the services with the latest container image from any kind of incoming events?
Currently using below CLI command to execute one by one manually. Is there any automated way to implement auto deployment for all the service one after another or in parallel.

```
gcloud run deploy SERVICE --image IMAGE_URL
```

Addn: Labels are been used to mark the 25 containers which have the same container images. Not required to build docker image everytime from source. The same image can be used.

Comment: What are the bottlenecks or issues faced with the command line solution?

Comment: Use Cloud Build. Add a step to deploy to each Cloud Run service. Then each time you build the container, the container will be automatically deployed.

Comment: @tmarwen this needs to be triggered without manual intervention to deploy all containers on some triggers.

Comment: @JohnHanley using autodeployment available in Cloudrun using CloudBuild creating the new image everytime. It needs to be single image deployed in multiple service.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Cloud Build can deploy the **same** container image to any number of Cloud Run services. I am not referring to the Cloud Build integration with the Cloud Run GUI. I mean you can write a Cloud Build configuration to deploy your container image on build.

Comment: Sorry, was confused with the "Continous Deployment" button in Cloudrun UI.
Can you share any code sample to collect the list of services using labels or input arguments and iterate the deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case *Terraform* is an option for you, you can automate all *Cloud Run* services deployment using either with the `count` or `for_each` meta-arguments:

### `count` if you need the same service name with indexes

```yaml
provider "google" {
    project = "MY-PROJECT-ID"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
    count    = 25
    name     = "MY-SERVICE-${count.index}"
    location = "MY-REGION"

    metadata {
      annotations = {
        "run.googleapis.com/client-name" = "terraform"
      }
    }

    template {
      spec {
        containers {
          image = "IMAGE_URL"
        }
      }
    }
 }

 data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
   binding {
     role = "roles/run.invoker"
     members = ["allUsers"]
   }
 }

 resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
   for_each    = google_cloud_run_service.default
   location    = each.value.location
   project     = each.value.project
   service     = each.value.name

   policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
 }
```

where `MY-PROJECT-ID` and `MY-REGION` needs to be replaced with your project specific values.

### `for_each` if you need different service names

```yaml
provider "google" {
    project = "MY-PROJECT-ID"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
    for_each = toset( ["Service 1", "Service 2", "Service 25"] )
    name     = each.key
    location = "MY-REGION"

    metadata {
      annotations = {
        "run.googleapis.com/client-name" = "terraform"
      }
    }

    template {
      spec {
        containers {
          image = "IMAGE_URL"
        }
      }
    }
 }

 data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
   binding {
     role = "roles/run.invoker"
     members = ["allUsers"]
   }
 }

 resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
   for_each    = google_cloud_run_service.default
   location    = each.value.location
   project     = each.value.project
   service     = each.value.name

   policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
 }
```

where `MY-PROJECT-ID` and `MY-REGION` needs to be replaced with your project specific values as well.

You can refer to the official [*GCP Cloud Run* documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#service) for further details on *Terraform* usage.

Comment: Is it possible to have dynamic inventory based on labels or any other mechanism instead of hard coding the service name in the terraform code?

Comment: Also facing this error https://pasteboard.co/MIJNB1eS1XYK.png

Comment: I missed mapping the `google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy` resource for each Cloud Run service.