# How to deploy Django Application with Celery + Reddis on Google Cloud Run (docker-compose)

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery, google-cloud-run

I have a `docker-compose.prod.yaml` containing 7 services which I'd like to deploy to Google [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run). I like the benefits of a serverless solution, to my understanding the two other options are:

1. Google [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine), however [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897341/8790344) suggest multiple containers isn't possible
2. GKE is a good fit but we're a small team without a dedicated DevOps engineer or internal Kubernetes expertise which is what would be required

Is deploying such application possible on Google Cloud Run or even desirable? Some guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. I'm favouring simplicity and cost efficiency.

Some potential issues I'm foreseeing:

1. Setting up networking between containers
2. Instances are destroyed within 15 minutes
3. Connecting all the volumes together
4. Deploying 7 containers individually potentially tedious

I do acknowledge that Google offers [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) however, that would tie us to GCP and we'd miss the extensive functionality of Celery.

One of the changes made to the `docker-compose.prod.yaml` will be switching the `db` container for a [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql) managed instance.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

  nginx:
    build: ./compose/production/nginx
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
      - mediafiles:/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 5555:5555
      - 15672:15672
    depends_on:
      - web
      - flower

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
      - mediafiles:/app/mediafiles
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.prod-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django

  redis:
    image: redis:6-alpine

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: django_celery_example_celery_worker
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
      - mediafiles:/app/mediafiles
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.prod-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  celery_beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: django_celery_example_celery_beat
    command: /start-celerybeat
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
      - mediafiles:/app/mediafiles
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.prod-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  flower:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: django_celery_example_celery_flower
    command: /start-flower
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
      - mediafiles:/app/mediafiles
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.prod-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  staticfiles:
  mediafiles:
```

This docker setup was largely taken from [this course](https://testdriven.io/courses/django-celery/docker/) and is very convenient for development. As a data-centric company we're most familiar with GCP, so would prefer to stick with it for now.

This is what the config file structure looks like:

```
├── compose
│   ├── local
│   │   └── django
│   │       ├── Dockerfile
│   │       ├── celery
│   │       │   ├── beat
│   │       │   │   └── start
│   │       │   ├── flower
│   │       │   │   └── start
│   │       │   └── worker
│   │       │       └── start
│   │       ├── entrypoint
│   │       └── start
│   └── production
│       ├── django
│       │   ├── Dockerfile
│       │   ├── celery
│       │   │   ├── beat
│       │   │   │   └── start
│       │   │   ├── flower
│       │   │   │   └── start
│       │   │   └── worker
│       │   │       └── start
│       │   ├── entrypoint
│       │   └── start
│       └── nginx
│           ├── Dockerfile
│           └── nginx.conf
├── django_celery_example
│     # files omitted for brevity
├── docker-compose.prod.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── manage.py
├── polls
│     # files omitted for brevity
└── requirements.txt
```

Comment: If you want to deploy services automatically, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69617491/18265570)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but when you say **Redis** and **DB Container** you can not run it on Cloud Run however there is always a **workaround** i read somewhere running **DB** on **Cloud Run**.

Cloud Run is a good fit for **stateless** **containers** while **DB** and **Redis** store the states in the filesystem, and memory. You might have to do some plan for **Redis** as for DB **cloudSQL** there.

**Some potential issues I'm foreseeing:**

- Setting up networking between containers

**GKE** might could be a better fit considering the Redis & DB container to Run and you can deploy and create networking as per requirement and give your flexibility.

- Connecting all the volumes together

Either you use [Cloud bucket fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) or use shared filesytem or with [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) you upload files to bucket. However if it's necessary to share volume across PODs **ReadWrieMany** with **NFS** would be best option.

- Deploying 7 containers individually potentially tedious

You can also use [Kompose](https://kompose.io/) which will convert you **Docker compose** to **Kubernetes** **YAML** - Ref : [Docker-compose to deploy to Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/)

**Extra (Skaffold & helm)**

Use the [Skaffold](https://skaffold.dev/) or [Helm chart](https://helm.sh/) template to have to manage the single/different values(variable files storing service-related details).